# How to have an iOS Phonegap app send data to Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: php, ios, mysql, cordova, phonegap-plugins

After having spent several hours looking into the matter and searched for a solution, I'm hoping someone out here can help me out and give me some hints.

My project, in a nutshell, is this:

> Using Phonegap/Cordova, I want to create a one page iPad "form" app from which the submitted data should eventually get to a Google Spreadsheet.

The idea is for a hair dresser who would like to log his employees transactions: `[Employee name], [Male/Female/Child haircut], [multiple choice "options": Shampoo, etc], [Amount charged], [Visa/Mastercard / Check / Cash]`

I've looked into several "solutions":

- Email the form, then use a Google Script + RegEx to grab the data and populate the sheet. (This sounds ugly, no?)
- Submit the data to a .php webservice (forgive me if I'm using the wrong terminology!) to populate a database stored on my VPS (MySQL?), then use a Google Script to fetch the data a regular intervals to populate the sheet.
- Submit the data to Parse and, again, use Google Script or a parse.com API if they have any.

[Here's a very rough draft of what the app would look like](http://coisne.me/lecoiffeur/) (it doesn't need to be fancy)

[Sketch of the concept](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLY1k.png)

Any hint would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance...